# Why is it required to become a view function to declare a local variable as memory?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

My code has been given here.

```
contract PureMem{
    uint[] public arr=[1,2,3,4];
    function Mem() public view{
        uint[] memory arrm=arr;
        arrm[1]=192;    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not required.

The compiler only gives a warning (i.e. recommendation to fix) that the function should be declared with the `view` modifier when it only reads from the storage but doesn't write there.